# Parse - Anonymous user's authData field becomes undefined

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using anonymous user feature of parse in my App. The strange behaviour I find is sometimes the authData field become undefined for the Anonymous user.[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: It won't sometimes become undefined. I think you probably need to check your code first.

Comment: What I am doing is first I enable the anonymous user and save that to cloud. Then I link that user with Facebook.

Comment: Go check your code instead.  I can't help you with what you just describe.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same trouble, but when I consume the user in my cloud code, the authData has the "anonymous" key:

user Class:
[image: parse user class]

Cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(req,res) {    
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = req.user;
    console.log(user);
    var data = user.get("authData");
    console.log(data);
    res.success("ok");
});
```

parse response:

[image: parse cloud code response]

So, no matter if in the dashboard is "undefined" because in the "authData" is ok!!

I hopefully that this solve your problem